# RXSwift flatmap that returns from an async completion handler

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am trying to create a searchBar that searches for addresses via a MKLocalSearch with request and using RXSwift and binding to RXCocoa

So far i have done the following
1. filter and debounce to avoid too many requests:

```
let searchRes = searchBar.rx.text
    .orEmpty
    .filter { query in
        return query.characters.count > 4
    }
    .debounce(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
```

2. the resulting String query is map:ed to create a MKLocationSearch and then flatMapp:ed to return an array of MKMapItems to be able to bind the array to tableView's items:

   ```
   searchRes.map{query -> MKLocalSearch in
       let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
       request.naturalLanguageQuery = query
       request.region = self.mapView.region
       return MKLocalSearch(request: request)
   }.flatMapLatest{search -> Observable<[MKMapItem]> in
       search.start(completionHandler:{(response, error) in
           let items: Variable<[MKMapItem]> = Variable([])
           if let resp = response {
               //need to return the result form this
               // i.e. items.value = response.mapItems
           }
           //can not return from here since the request is async
       }
   }.bindTo //continue to bind to tableview
   ```

How can this be done using RXSwift, i could not find any relevant example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create an Observable with the ansync request. You could define the following method to do that:

```
func mapItems(for searchRequest: MKLocalSearch) -> Observable<[MKMapItem]> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        searchRequest.start(completionHandler: { (response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                observer.onError(error)
            } else {
                let items = response?.mapItems ?? []
                observer.onNext(items)
                observer.onCompleted()
            }
        })

        return Disposables.create {
            searchRequest.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just use `flatMapLatest` with that method:

```
searchRes
    .map { query -> MKLocalSearch in
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = query
        request.region = self.mapView.region
        return MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    }
    .flatMapLatest{ [unowned self] search -> Observable<[MKMapItem]> in
        self.mapItems(for: search)
    }
    .bindTo(....
```

Comment: thank you, still exploring the depths of RX and this part was always not well documentend